# How to use Spring Boot Activity Rest api in Activity App Ui

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, activiti

I am new to Activity process. I want to used the Activity with spring boot application. So, I want to used the rest api in spring boot and that rest api will be used by activiti-admin.war and activiti-app.war.

So, when I have deployed process from spring boot that will be available in UI and add some Listener while assigning task will be called in my spring boot app.

Can any one help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the version 6 Activiti build.
Both the activiti-app and admin-app already use "a" REST API to communicate to the backend, however it is not the community REST API that will be deployed with your Spring boot application (I assume you are using the Activiti spring boot starter rest).

It is not actually going to be trivial to separate the activiti-app and admin-app UI from the service layer as they are quite tightly coupled, but it is certainly possible.
While I haven't actually attempted it, it may be easiest to take the activiti-app build module (activiti-ui/activiti-app) and separate the client and server portions since the client is now a regular AngularJS application.

Is this what you are looking for?
Thanks,
Greg

Comment: Actually I want to used the Listener while Complete the User task which is available in Spring boot app. Can you explain or provide example code for that and How you changed the url of Rest Api.

Comment: Task and execution listeners are available as a core feature of the engine. They have no dependency on Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for something like [this](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/issues/1437). It seems they are planning to support activiti app with your own spring boot application in Activiti 7.

If you are able to solve the case, please help with the sample structure. I am bit stuck with same usecase.